# First users by categories in BigQuery

Tags: sql, datetime, count, google-bigquery, distinct

How can I count the new and existing users by categories and years?

For instance, during 2015-2020 if someone bought a product in category_A in 2016 first, it will be counted as a new uesr in 2016 in category_A although this user bought a product in category_B in 2015.

Table_1 (Columns: product_name, date, category, sales, user_id)

Want to get the result as bleow

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select extract(year from mindate) yr, category, count(*) num_new
from (
    select user_id, category, min(date) mindate
    from table_1
    group by user_id, category
) t
group by extract(year from mindate)
```

The subquery retrieves the first purchase date of each user by category. Then, the outer query aggregates by the year of that date.

---

If you want the count of current users as well, then it is a bit different. You can use a window function in the subquery rather than aggregation, then count distinct values in the outer query:

```
select extract(year from mindate) yr, category, 
    countdistinctif(user_id, date = mindate) num_new,
    countdistinct(user_id) num_total
from (
    select date, user_id, category, min(date) over(partition by user_id, category) mindate
    from table_1
) t
group by extract(year from mindate)
```

Comment: Thanks!! How can I count existing users number together?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT *, 
    0 = COUNT(1) OVER(
      PARTITION BY user_id, category 
      ORDER BY date 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) new_user
  FROM `project.dataset.table_1`
  ORDER BY date, user_id
)
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year,
  category,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(new_user, user_id, NULL)) AS num_new,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(new_user, NULL, user_id)) AS num_existing  
FROM temp
GROUP BY year, category
```

Comment: If I change 1=COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, category 
      ORDER BY date 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) new_user,  Is the logic also right? When I run the query it seems work, but just wanted to double check. Thanks!